# How do I create an account with Corda?

Tags: corda

I am currently creating a banking system at Corda,

Two nodes are running,

・Notary Node

・BankA Node

I want to create an account in BankA,

Q1. How do I create an account on BankA?

Q2. Is it possible to check existence of created account by contract or flow?

Would you be able to lend your expertise,

Comment: I think Cordite (an open sourced CorDapp) could help you here. https://cordite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/concepts/dgl.html

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Let me check Cordite!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create the account(State) in BankA
1. Implement the flow for create the account
2. Implement the command for validate state

and you can check existing account in the flow

In you case the participant is only BankA

The sample flow check link below
https://github.com/corda/cordapp-example/blob/release-V3/kotlin-source/src/main/kotlin/com/example/flow/ExampleFlow.kt

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply!
I see! Which means...
State is data,
Flow is processing,